# PrimeFaces commandButton to set edit mode and refresh the form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to have a button that sets edit mode and refreshes the form, but by clicking the button, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Edit Your Records" icon="ui-icon-edit"
                         update="@form" rendered="#{!bean.editMode}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{bean.editMode}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Exit Edit Mode" icon="ui-icon-back" 
                         update="@form" rendered="#{bean.editMode}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{bean.editMode}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.table}" var="apartment">
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the affected `value` attribute to the `target` one, should be expressed in EL: `value="#{true}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Edit Your Records" update="@form" rendered="#{!bean.editMode}" action="#{bean.toggleEditMode()}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Exit Edit Mode" update="@form" rendered="#{bean.editMode}" action="#{bean.toggleEditMode()}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.editMode}" />
```

and

```
public void toggleEditMode() {
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seams that the function called in the 'action' attribute needs to return a String.

The following worked:

```
public String toggleEditMode() {
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
    return "#";
}
```

Thanks!